# What iMac colour profile provides stable colour palettes with Microsoft 365 for Mac?

Tags: color, rgb, palette, microsoft-office

**PROBLEM:**
I designed a custom Powerpoint theme on Microsoft 365 for Mac. It appeared to save but when I reopened the file, the RGB value of one colour changed by a value of 1. (R=98 dropped to R=97) I tried several times and it consistently drops. I contacted Microsoft Support and they have never seen this problem. Apple, currently has limited support options and I couldn't find anything in their help material.

**QUESTIONS:**

Is it possible that my iMac colour profile cannot register this shade of gray (R98 G99 B97) and changes it to the nearest value (R97 G99 B97)?

Any recommendations for a colour profile that works best with Microsoft 365 for Mac on an iMac?

Any other ideas how to resolve this?

**MY COMPUTER:**
2017 iMac with 27" 5k monitor; iMac colour profile; Radeon Pro 575 4GB; Catalina v10.15.4;

Comment: **Thank you!**  This is VERY helpful. The change in colour isn't perceptible to the naked eye so I will leave well enough alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>moved from comment</sup>

---

Microsoft products are **notoriously** bad where color is concerned. Their support may have been less than forthcoming. You do NOT want to alter Apple profiles to fix some Microsoft Office issue.

Everything in Office uses RGB color. RGB has a habit of changing values based upon *which* computer is opening the document. You simply **can't** control RGB to any great degree across multiple systems. The *best* you can do is try and use a common RGB color profile like sRGB. So, if an app/system is using that color profile the RGB values *may* be similar. However, Microsoft Office doesn't *really* color manage *anything*. They assume anyone using there software just wants "red" or "green" or "blue" or "grey" and aren't concerned with a variance in actual RGB values as long as the general "grey" is still "grey" to the eye.

Change the PPT file to a color PowerPoint won't randomly decide to alter. Microsoft Office and all it's products have never cared about accurate color. Not *ever*. For Office and RGB color *"close enough"* has always been the best it does. You're **never** going to correct a single-digit hex value variance in Powerpoint.

Comment: also color management is a bit random when you want it to work on random devices. I have to this day still not seen a projector (in sub 30k range) that can keep color calibration for more than a few days.

Comment: @joojaa Indeed! And even if a given projector were stable/predictable, room-lighting, bulb aging and other factors would make a fixed profile inaccurate. IF PPT were able to use one. That's why at one point Macbeth (now XRite) developed a color calibration device and PPT add-in for projectors, but it didn't last long on the market. Maybe MS had already learned that dead-accurate color just wasn't that important to the vast majority of their users, so chose not to invest in it. And apparently there weren't enough outliers to make the calibration device/software commercially viable.